# Decrease dot size in matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

The default dot size in matplotlib plots feel a bit bigger than what I would prefer - the tiny ones on a gnuplot plot. Is there a way to do so? The 'linewidth=x.y' (kind of obviously) doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using `ax.scatter` (or similar) methods, the keyword-argument is `s`. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html).

Alternatively, if you're using `ax.plot`, and using markers, the keyword-argument is `markersize` or `ms` ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html)).

Comment: Well, this works but decreases the brightness of the points. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?